# Listar dados em um List View

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Estou estudando programação para Android, estou fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados SQLite, porem não consigo jogar os dados obtidos em um listview, ele sempre me retorna a minha string na íntegra ao invés do valor do banco.

Esta é minha função que faz o select

```
private boolean VerificaRegistro(){

        try{
        BancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase(NomeBanco, MODE_PRIVATE ,null);
        cursor = BancoDados.rawQuery("select * from tabcadastropessoa", null);
        
        if(cursor.getCount()!=0){
            cursor.getCount();
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
        }catch(Exception erro){
        MensagemAlerta("Erro no Banco de Dados", "Não foi possível gverificar dados"
                + erro);
        return false;
        }
        finally{
            BancoDados.close();
        }
    }
```

Esta é minha função para listar no listview

```
public void CarregaDados(){

        lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.LvMostraDados);
        VerificaRegistro();
            String[] Coluna = new String[]{"nomepessoa"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                    Coluna);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Essa é a imagem de como me retorna os dados
[image: Imagem do projeto]

Comment: Tiago, onde você está preenchendo seu objeto para mostrar na listView?

Comment: Você está passando "Coluna" como um atributo para inflar sua listView, posta seu o código fonte do seu Adapter para podermos dar uma olhada.

Comment: Você vai ao banco apenas através de `VerificaRegistro()` mas ele não retorna dado algum, apenas verifica se existem.